# Style links NOT within a certain element

Tags: css, class, selector

Using child selectors I can alter only the 'a' elements within the 'p' tag, but is there a similar way to change only those NOT within the 'p' tag? Adding an additional class isn't an option.

So using the fiddle as an example, I want a way to change the background color of 'Link 1', 'Link 2' and 'Link 3' other than using the universal '.links' class.

http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/Nuy9a/

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href="#" class="links">click me</a></p>
<a href="#" class="links">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="links">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="links">Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this would not be possible with pure CSS since there is currently [no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

You could, however, use the following work-around. Just style all the `.links` elements. Then just reset the styling by selecting `.links` elements that are children of `p` elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3C2DB/)

```
.links {
    background-color:#ccc;
}

p > .links {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

As an alternative, you could also use the following. It's worth noting that this method will *only* work with your current HTML. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/AX9cH/)

```
p ~ a.links {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

---

If you want a jQuery solution, you could use the following. It will select all `a` elements that are not children of `p` elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpK2S/)

```
$('a:not(p a)').css('background','#ccc');
```

Comment: I didn't think so but just wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was missing... your in-depth explanation and alternative ideas were much appreciated though so thank you!